# MPI_Iprobe vs MPI_Probe

Tags: mpi

In MPI_Iprobe, one needs to check for the flag several times to actually find out if there is any messages, one way to do this is to put it in a while loop, I wonder if this approach is equivalent to MPI_Probe
because basically it blocks the probing in a different way, 
Is this a wrong way of using Iprobe?

```
int flag=0
while(flag==0)
{
MPI_Iprobe(MPI_ANY_SOURCE, MPI_ANY_TAG, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &flag,&status);
cout<<myrank<<" "<<flag<<endl;
}
if(flag)
{
 MPI_Get_count(&status, MPI_INT, &count);

 MPI_Irecv(&rcvbuff,count, MPI_INT,destination.at(0),0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &request);

}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, basically a loop around `MPI_Iprobe` like you suggest has the same semantic as a `MPI_Probe`. However, you should generally **prefer the the compound operation instead of implementing it on your own**. So use `MPI_Probe` instead of the `MPI_Iprobe`-loop. Use `MPI_Wait` instead of a `MPI_Test`-loop. Use collectives instead of individual point-to-point messages whenever possible.

The synchronous `MPI_I...` functions are generally useful if you want to overlap communication with computation, but you should not use them to re-implement existing MPI functionality.

By using `MPI_Probe` you give the implementation the freedom for optimization and tuning. On the one hand, MPI can block until a message comes, saving CPU cycles / power. On the other hand it can have a lower latency because no time is wasted entering the MPI stack again and again. It is also nicer to any tools using the PMPI layer to use one `MPI_Probe` call instead of thousands of `MPI_Iprobe` calls. I have achieved > 10% speedup in real world HPC applications simply by replacing a `MPI_Test`-loop with `MPI_Waitany`.

The only exception is if you have exhausted the tuning options of your MPI implementation and can definitely show that your own reimplementation of the wheel performs better than the compound operation offered by MPI.

The `MPI_Irecv` call is also rather odd. Do you have a good reason to use an asynchronous receive despite knowing that there already is a pending message? Why not post the `MPI_Irecv` instead of probing in the first place? If you know the maximum size needed for allocating the receive buffer, you can also post an `MPI_Irecv` on `MPI_ANY_SOURCE` with a receive count that is larger than the send count.

Comment: @DrJ you do not need to know the size, a maximum size will suffice. Since I don't see you allocating `rcvbuff` in your code, I did assume that is done in advance of knowing the size.

Comment: This is just a simple test case, in fact I do not know the maximum size since it changes based on the calculations, thanks for your helpful comments though