# Code freezes when trying to append data received from MPI_recv with mpi4py

Tags: mpi, mpi4py

I have some code where I am trying to communicate data across processors. I have a nested list of `neighbors`, in which each element reperesents a subsection of the data, and the elements of that list are integer values of the MPI process assigned to it. For example, dividing the data into 3 subsections each with 1 MPI process -> `neighbors=[[0],[1],[2]]`.

The subsections of the problem work usually work independently, but every so often I need to communicate pieces of the data between the subections. So each processor loops through its neighboring subsections of data and the processors assigned to it and makes a nonblocking send (isend) and blocking receive (recv). The code seems to be working, except when I try to append the received data to one large list.

Here is the blocking receive section of the code:

```py
    bankr = []
    # for each neighbor (subsection of data)
    for name in neighbors:
        # for each processor asigned to that neighbor
        for source in neighbors[name]:
            # blocking test for a message:
            if MPI.COMM_WORLD.probe(source=source):
                received = MPI.COMM_WORLD.recv(source=source)
                print('rank ', mcdc["mpi_rank"], "received shape ", received.shape)
                # bankr.extend(received)
```

When the last line `bankr.extend(received)` is left out, it seems everything runs as it should. For example, if I were to split up the computing into 3 subsections each with one processor assigned, the `neighbors` variable would look like `neighbors=[[0],[1],[2]] and I get the output:`

```
rank  0 sent message to  1
rank  0 received shape  (8,)
rank  1 sent message to  2
rank  1 sent message to  0
rank  1 received shape  (49,)
rank  1 received shape  (53,)
rank  2 sent message to  1
rank  2 received shape  (9,)
```

Which is what I would expect. But if I uncomment the last line `bankr.extend(received)` where I'm simply trying to append all of the data received to one large list the code freezes after printing

```
rank  0 sent message to  1
rank  0 received shape  (8,)
```

Is there something obvious I'm doing wrong?

Comment: out of curiosity, why do you `if MPI.COMM_WORLD.probe(...)`?

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet basically because I want there to be a "while any unreceived messages from neighbors" loop. I originally had a `while loop` + `MPI_iprobe` but learned from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43823458/mpi-iprobe-vs-mpi-probe) that's essentially the function of `MPI_probe`.

Comment: That sounds a bit convoluted. IIRC the `mpi4py` binding, `probe()` blocks until a message is available, and then always return true, so it should be equivalent to skipping the `probe()` and simply issue a `recv()`. Post a [mcve] if you are still stuck so I can reproduce and debug it.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet This is a feature in a much larger code - I spent some time making a minimal reproducible example for you and realized the bug was not in any of the MPI calls, it was in an outer while loop. MPI is working as expected. Thank you!